# Split data day wise

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have data files with time epoch (UNIX time) and I am trying to split the data day/date wise in separate files. Eg: The data is for 90 days so it should be spited to 90 files. I do not know how to start with it. Sometime I know the number days and sometimes I dont know so to have an ease I am trying to find a better way to simply split the data day/date wise. `Data[0] Data[1] Timeepoch[2] Timeepoch[3]`. `Time_1 and Time_2` are the start time and stop time.

Data:These are only few lines.

```
Data_1  Data_2  Time_1  Time_2
3436    1174    1756908 1759291
3436    3031    1756908 1759291
3436    1349    1756908 1759291
5372    937     1756913 1756983
4821    937     1756913 1756983
4376    937     1756913 1756983
2684    937     1756913 1756983
3826    896     1756961 1756971
3826    896     1756980 1756997
5372    937     1756983 1757045
4821    937     1756983 1757045
4376    937     1756983 1757045
2684    937     1756983 1757045
3826    896     1757003 1757053
4944    3715    1757009 1757491
4944    4391    1757009 1757491
2539    1431    1757014 1757337
5372    937     1757045 1757104
4821    937     1757045 1757104
4376    937     1757045 1757104
2684    937     1757045 1757104
896     606     1757053 1757064
3826    896     1757064 1757074
5045    4901    1757074 1757085
4921    4901    1757074 1757085
4901    3545    1757074 1757085
4901    3140    1757074 1757085
4901    4243    1757074 1757085
896     606     1757074 1757084
```

Comment: [`date.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) might come in helpful.

Comment: These are some strange timestamps, though.

Comment: Yes they are a bit strange.

Comment: What does it mean: "Both the timestamps are to be considered"? Do you want a middle date between the timestamps? Provide several examples, that show how do you want to get a single day from two timestamps.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian No NO .. What this is doing is perfect. I am just about the change the update block now. I have a second step with the time epoch so i was facing some difficulty in that but now i have changed the order of steps and this works for me.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools
import datetime

# Extract the date from the timestamp that is the third item in a line
# (Will be grouping by start timestamp)
def key(s):
    return datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(s.split()[2]))

with open('in.txt') as in_f:
    for date, group in itertools.groupby(in_f, key=key):
        # Output to file that is named like "1970-01-01.txt"
        with open('{:%Y-%m-%d}.txt'.format(date), 'w') as out_f:
            out_f.writelines(group)
```

Comment: are you sure that local date is unambiguous (monotonous)? It is for common timezones. Does it true for all of them? It is why I use UTC date in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25753844/4279) that is known to be unique (doesn't repeat ever). Another issue: `groupby()` fails if the data is not sorted. It is common that timestamps in the input data are not monotonous for various reasons. This is why I use `daily_files` dictionary (90 entries) in my answer (that works whatever the order).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian This solution is so elegant and efficient that I just couldn't not write it. Yes, your warnings apply. Our answers may be combined in some way, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, it may loose data if `in_f` is not sorted by the `key`. You could take the necessary parts from my answer, to fix it.

Comment: nano-nitpick: [`writelines()` may create a list unnecessarily](http://bugs.python.org/issue21910). To support large files, you could write line by line instead (though I don't think it is necessary to change the code in this case)

Comment: Thanks This is the simplest way i see. Thanks again and shall consider what @J.F.Sebastian discusses about the UTC date.

Comment: How can I change the output file name from `'{:%Y-%m-%d}.txt'` to `{:%Y-%m-%d_Day/time+}.txt'` Day/Time count to be incremented.

Comment: I found a small error with the output the first line of every file in output has previous day data.

Answer (score 1):

To find a UTC date from the POSIX timestamp, just add it to the Epoch e.g.:

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> date(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=1756908)
datetime.date(1970, 1, 21)
```

Then create a mapping: `date -> file` and use it to split the input file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_date(line, epoch=date(1970, 1, 1)):
    try:
        timestamp = int(line.split()[2]) # timestamp from 3rd column
        return epoch + timedelta(seconds=timestamp) # UTC date
    except Exception:
        return None # can't parse timestamp

daily_files = {} # date -> file
input_file = fileinput.input()
next(input_file) # skip header
for line in input_file:
    d = get_date(line)
    file = daily_files.get(d)
    if file is None: # file for the given date is not found
       file = daily_files[d] = open(str(d), 'w') # open a new one
    file.write(line)

# close all files
for f in daily_files.values():
    try:
        f.close()
    except EnvironmentError:
        pass # ignore errors
```

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)`

can get you a datetime object from a timestamp and

`datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).replace(second=0, minute=0, hour=0)`

can get you a datetime object with just the date component.

Answer (score 0):

The next code will write each line to a file named output-YYYY-MM-DD, where YYYY-MM-DD is extracted from the Time_2 column.

> ```
> from datetime import date
> with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f:
>     for line in f: 
>         fields = line.split()
>         with open('output-'+date.fromtimestamp(float(fields[3])).__str__(), 'a') as outf:
>             outf.write(line)
> ```

This code is not very efficient. It opens a file for each line. It could be improved if you can assure that the input data is sorted by end_time.